# How to identify models in sunspot multiple model search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot

I want to search store, chart and last model.
For the time and coordinate, I put the id in the session.
I want to use the id for other purpose.
Is there any possible way that I can identify the source model of id?

```
@searchs = Sunspot.search store, chart, last do |s|
      s.fulltext params[:search]
      s.with(:end_at).greater_than(Time.now) 
    end.results
    ar=[]
    @searchs.each do |a|
      if a.coordinate_x.nil? || a.coordinate_y.nil?
        next
      end
      ar << a.id 
    end
    session[:stores_id] = ar
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to store more information to be able to identify the source model. You can get and store the name of the class when you are iterating over the results. Based on this information you can identify the source model be examining the type.

```
@searchs = Sunspot.search store, chart, last do |s|
  s.fulltext params[:search]
  s.with(:end_at).greater_than(Time.now) 
end.results
ar=[]
@searchs.each do |a|
  if a.coordinate_x.nil? || a.coordinate_y.nil?
    next
  end
  # Store the type of the item and its id.
  ar << {type: a.class.name, id: a.id}
end
session[:stores_id] = ar
```